# Alternative ways to get past 32 rpz zone limit in BIND? ...without running BIND a thousand times

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, opendns, unbound, rpz

Using BIND RPZs gives me exactly what I'm looking for to alter queries. However, my recursive DNS server is in use by hundreds of clients and I am looking for a way to allow each client some level of customization. There's possibly a couple hundred zones a client might want to enable making for thousands of different possible combinations.

It appears I am limited to 32 RPZ zones (of seemingly infinite length) but that alone won't work -- each user needs the ability to opt-in to specific zones. Even with massive zones for each client it will still hit the 32 limit.

I've looked briefly at Unbound which appears to have a similar sort of RPZ setup with local-data transparency, but the fun seems to have ended when looking for a way to separate things into views so I can only serve them to specific clients.

Surely there's a way to accomplish this without reinventing the wheel? I see commercial providers offering similar setups, like OpenDNS for example where thousands of customers can toggle various lists. What's the secret sauce?

Comment: What are you trying to do for which you think RPZs are the solution? This has a definite smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730). **Tell us what problem you are actually trying to solve by doing this,** and we might be able to suggest *actual solutions to your problem*.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for the reply. I am trying to alter DNS query responses based on the fqdn being queried and at times based on the response returned. But not all clients will have the same things altered which is why I am trying to somehow conjure up different views allowing more than the 32 limit within BIND. I believe the alternative, just using a master zone for each domain would break other subdomains for select sites. (at least that's what happened when I tried it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it helps to understand why the limitation exists.

> https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01121
>
> The RPZ mechanism has not changed in BIND 9.10. The documentation in
> KB article AA-00525 (Building DNS Firewalls with Response Policy Zones
> (RPZ)is still almost current. What has changed in BIND 9.10 is that it
> is now possible to use as many as 32 separate RPZ files in a single
> instance of BIND, and that BIND is not significantly slowed by such
> heavy use of RPZ.  Each one of those 32 policy zone files can specify
> policy for as many different domains as necessary. The limit of 32 is
> on the number of independently-specified policy collections and not
> the number of zones for which they specify policy.
>
> In earlier versions of BIND in which RPZ was implemented, having more
> than one RPZ zone file required BIND to perform a separate lookup in
> each policy zone to see if there was a match. In BIND 9.10, the policy
> information is stored in a radix tree, in which simultaneous lookups
> across all policy zones can be performed in sub-linear time that is
> approximately proportional to the logarithm of the number of policy
> statements in the largest collection (RPZ zone).
>
> The improved implementation of RPZ for BIND 9.10 was provided by
> Vernon Schryver and Paul Vixie. It is faster because it is O(log n) in
> the size of the policy and because it can look up several items of
> data in parallel. **The new limit of 32 results from the use of a 32-bit
> bitfield to identify the policy zones that affect a query.  Previous
> implementations of RPZ were O(n) rather than O(log n).**

I've emphasized the relevant verbiage. The only way to change the limit of 32 is to update the algorithm to use a larger bitfield, or gut the optimization code entirely. Even if you were to double the size of the bitfield to 64 (or re-double to 128, etc.), you're still dealing with a static limitation imposed by the radix tree optimization. Since I'm not familiar with the innards of this algorithm, I also can't say how effective such an attempt would be to begin with.

You can get around this by using views that match your individual customers, which will give you 32 RPZ zones per customer, but that's as far as you're going to get without diving into the source code.

Comment: I see where the limitation is spoken about but don't know enough to modify the source to change anything like this unfortunately. I don't think I can get the 32 zones per client according to "There can be up to 32 zone definitions (BIND 9.10+). Each zone defined in the response-policy statement must also be defined within a normal zone clause, which may, in turn, be inside a view clause..." (ref http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html ) but I'll absolutely give this a go. If indeed I can, this meets me needs quite nicely!

Comment: It depends on whether or not each instanced view is assigned its own bitfield. (and frankly, it would make no sense if they shared one) Considering the fact that each view can be assigned its own exclusive list of associated RPZs (did a quick test in my lab earlier today), I strongly suspect that this will work.

Comment: Well I'll be! That seemed to work as I wanted despite the text leaving me feeling like it wouldn't (the way I read the text hinted the views may be optional, leaving me thinking the limit still applied). This is fantastic news. Thank you Andrew!

Comment: The docs have moved to https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01121; I archived them at https://web.archive.org/web/20210529204605/https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01121
I also archived http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html as https://web.archive.org/web/20210529204934/http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/rpz.html